# Help in proving linear algebra about inverse of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

can anyone please help?

Given:
$\vec{x}$ - vector of rational numbers,
$C$ - covariance matrix $C=(\vec x - \overline x)(\vec x - \overline x )^\top$

Prove:
$C^{-1} =P^\top P$.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I also bet you git the definition wrong